# XCode iTunesconnect login

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I am having some troubles with Xcode login with account created through iTunes connect. I have no experience with developer program whatsoever so please help me if you can.

We have company account and the app on app store. External company is developing it for us. But we wanted to create another app, so my boss, admin on iTunes connect has given me app manager role. After that I have successfully created new app, but I cant get my Xcode to use that apple id as a team one, only personal. Also when I try to login to developer.apple.com it treats me like a regular new user, not like I am in company and my account and apple id has ben created via iTunes connect and asks me to enrol to developer program and I believe pay 99$.

I can see that I do not yet understand the process fully so please if anyone knows, give me some guide on my trouble.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

For anyone with similar problem, invitation in iTunes connect is not enough, you have to get invited to developer team on developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use your personal account? Make sure your account is registered at the developer website, even if you don't pay $99 for your personal account.

As for the Xcode issue, go to Xcode>Preferences>Accounts>Click +> Add your team account. Then, back at the list of files **inside your Xcode project**, click the icon all the way at the top. It should be the name of your app. Where it says team, click on that, and select your team account. Make sure you have created a provisioning profile. Xcode can do that for you if you haven't done that.

See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The problem was however somewhere else. My boss forgot to send me invitation to our team on developer.apple.com. So now it's finally working.

Answer (score 1):

Like kyleappdev said, go to Xcode>Preferences>Accounts. Add your team account. It may take a few seconds to update, but even if you added it, you have to actually add it to your project.